# Stop Mathematica from shortening output

Tags: output-formatting

I have long expressions in my Mathematica file, which gets shortened with `<<...>>` structures. How can I tell mathematica to not do this and show me the complete expression?

I've read the [Short and Shallow Output](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ShortAndShallowOutput.html) section of the documentation, but I don't see anything about preventing the shortening behaviour (my expressions don't get put into a box with a **Set Size Limit** button). I have tried to use `Short[..., <Large Number>]` but this doesn't make a difference, so I'm not sure what else to do.

This is an image of the sort of expression I'm working with (but the expression continues). It's basically a differential form (technically a 3-form) with algebraic coefficients:
[image]

**Edit:** I find that changing the size of `$OutputSizeLimit` does not improve the situation. In fact, on my system at least, for the variables I am working with, I see no change when I make `$OutputSizeLimit` much larger (i.e., 1000 times larger). Surely there must be a way to tell Mathematica to give the raw output in full, or something similar?

Comment: See [OutputSizeLimit](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OutputSizeLimit.html) and [$OutputSizeLimit](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$OutputSizeLimit.html)

Comment: For reference, what version and OS are you on?

Comment: @J.M.: Mathematica version 10.0 on Linux (amd64).

Answer (score 5):

You can set the output size limit using the `Preferences` dialog which can be accessed from the `Edit` menu:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, you can find the current output size limit programatically evaluating

```
$OutputSizeLimit
```

or

```
Options[EvaluationNotebook[], OutputSizeLimit]
```

and set the output size limit to a number of your choice, say `sizelimit`, using

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], OutputSizeLimit -> sizelimit]
```

Comment: I saw that menu option before and changed it from the default value (1048576) by a factor of 100 and then 1000 but that makes no difference. I'll attach an image of the sort of expression I'm trying to simply (but telling you how to generate it yourself would involve running a lot of mathematica code).