# Derivative of long expression renders Piecewise[…<<…>>…] in Jupyter notebook

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics, output-formatting, piecewise, jupyter-notebook

My mathematical problem is to solve the optimization problem:
$$ Max_{u} \quad \mathbb{E}[\gamma S-S^2]$$
where $$S= A_0 u X+a-\max(\alpha u X+b,0)$$
with $\gamma,A_0,a,\alpha,b$ some constants and $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$.

As a starting point, I was trying to compute the tedious expectation via

```
Expectation[gamma*(a0*u*x+a-Max[alp*u*x+b,0])-((a0*u*x+a-Max[alp*u*x+b,0]))^2, x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[mu, sig]]
```

and here is the output:
[image]

using the Wolfram Engine (via Jupyter Interface).
After that, I was trying to take the partial derivative with respect to $u$ using

```
D[%,u]
```

and it renders a very strange output:
[image]

My feeling is that the expression is so long that it is unable to display it so the problem is not from the mathematical difficulty but more from the display. I searched on stackexchange but couldn't find a similar issue.

Do you know what the exact issue is and I can get the proper derivative ?

Thanks a lot !

**Edit:** The problem is now solved thanks to the solution below. Since some people comment that they can't recover my output, here is the full Jupyter output:
[image]

Comment: The community [expects the following](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) from you: 
✅: A clear description of an on-topic problem or goal.
❌: A minimal working *Wolfram Language* code example, formatted, easy to *copy&paste*, in [Raw InputForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/RawInputForm.html) **Not images!**. 
❌. An example of what you expect as output.
❌. Some proof of minimal *Mathematica* knowledge. 
❌. Minimum due diligence: Share how you have searched the site and documentation, your attempts and reasons to believe an answer exists.

Comment: I get a `Piecewise` output from your `Expection[..]`, not what you show. (V13.1, Mac M1)

Comment: @MichaelE2, I guess that your computer is not sufficiently powerful...

Comment: I guess that's not a very likely explanation, though

Comment: Can't reproduce the mentioned output in _v12.3_ and _v13.1_. I don't think this is something related to the powfulness of computer. The real `Out[16]` can't be the one you show.

Comment: For your info, I added my full output. It may help you to reproduce the results.

Comment: OK, so you only cut part of the output in the first screenshot. Then please notice the `Out[1]` in **Edit** is exactly a `Piecewise[…]` function. It's the default 2D display (formally we call it `StandardForm`) of it. If you still don't understand what I mean, just execute e.g. `Piecewise[{{a, a > 0}}, -a]` and observe. For more info, check the document of [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html).

Comment: What's your OS, version of _WolframLanguageForJupyter_, etc? With Win10, [_WolframLanguageForJupyter v0.9.3_](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter/releases), Wolfram language v12.3, I cannot reproduce your output, the `Piecewise[…]` is still in its 2D form after differentiation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSOCF.png

Comment: Somewhat related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128406/1871

Comment: Thanks @xzczd for the details. I have also Windows 10, last version of WolframLanguage v.0.9.3 but Wolfram language 13.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

To get the simplest form you need to tell Mathematica any constraints on the variables. For example,

```
$Assumptions = {mu ∈ Reals, sig > 0, alp > 0, u > 0, b > 0};
```

`$Assumptions` will automatically be used by any function that uses the option `Assumptions` (e.g., `Expectation`, `FullSimplify`)

```
expr = Expectation[
   gamma*(a0*u*x + a - 
       Max[alp*u*x + b, 0]) - ((a0*u*x + a - Max[alp*u*x + b, 0]))^2, 
   x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[mu, sig]] // FullSimplify

(* 1/2 (-2 a^2 - 
   b (b + gamma) - (-2 a0 (b + gamma) + 
      alp (2 b + gamma)) mu u - (2 a0^2 - 2 a0 alp + alp^2) (mu^2 + 
      sig^2) u^2 + 2 a (b + gamma + (-2 a0 + alp) mu u) - 
   alp E^(-((b + alp mu u)^2/(2 alp^2 sig^2 u^2))) Sqrt[2/π]
     sig u (-2 a + b + 
      gamma + (-2 a0 + alp) mu u) + (-b (-2 a + b + 
         gamma) + (2 a alp + 2 a0 b - alp (2 b + gamma)) mu u - 
      alp (-2 a0 + alp) (mu^2 + sig^2) u^2) Erf[(b + alp mu u)/(
     Sqrt[2] alp sig u)]) *)
```

Taking the derivative

```
D[expr, u] // FullSimplify

(* a (-2 a0 + alp) mu + a0 (b + gamma) mu - 
 1/2 alp (2 b + gamma) mu - (2 a0^2 - 2 a0 alp + alp^2) (mu^2 + 
    sig^2) u + (
 E^(-((b + alp mu u)^2/(2 alp^2 sig^2 u^2)))
   sig (-2 a0 b - alp (-2 a + gamma + 2 (-2 a0 + alp) mu u)))/Sqrt[
 2 π] + 
 1/2 ((2 a alp + 2 a0 b - alp (2 b + gamma)) mu - 
    2 alp (-2 a0 + alp) (mu^2 + sig^2) u) Erf[(b + alp mu u)/(
   Sqrt[2] alp sig u)] *)
```